# opening /sudo[colon] triggers >1min delay on fresh install of Ubuntu Server

Tags: emacs, sudo, tramp

Running Ubuntu Server 16.10, `emacs -Q`, when I `C-x C-f` and type in "/sudo:", it hangs for more than a minute then proceeds as normal.

I didn't see anything in the "*Messages*" buffer.  Debugging tips?

Comment: Is this reproducible on the shell? If yes, that would help debugging things as it rules out Emacs as the cause and it could be related to things like http://serverfault.com/questions/38114/why-does-sudo-command-take-long-to-execute

Comment: Not reproducible from the shell.

Comment: Does it happen only for the `sudo` method? Or do you experience the same when typing "/ssh:" ?

Comment: Same thing happens with "/ssh:"

Comment: Hm, kinda hard to analyze as I cannot reproduce it.  Sorry.  Are you aware of the hints at the TRAMP FAQ? You can find it at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Frequently-Asked-Questions.html and it lists a few methods how to possibly speed things up.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Do you have any insights or pointers to documentation for debugging this?

Comment: The usual debugging tip. `(setq tramp-verbose 10)` and rerun the test. Look into the Tramp debug buffer whether you find something, otherwise contact me (or the Tramp mailing list) for support.